# InsertRow in JTable via array (array is populated by data) no errors

Tags: java, arrays, swing, netbeans, jtable

I am trying to retrieve the data from the database and show it at the JTable. I'm using NetBeans and in debugging I have noticed that data from database is actually retrieved and data is populated in the Array "Appointment" but somehow it goes through these lines of code (which should insert everything into the table) and stops as if everything is done without any errors, although in GUI there is nothing showing up. Your help would be really appreciated.

```
private void search(){

        try{
            Model_Customer[] appointment = Controller_ManageCustomer.FindCustomers(Searchtxt.getText());
            resultModel.setRowCount(0);

            for(int i = 0; i < appointment.length; i++)
                resultModel.insertRow(i,new Object[]{appointment[i].GetID(),appointment[i].GetFName(), appointment[i].GetLName(), appointment[i].GetRegistration(), appointment[i].GetMake(), appointment[i].GetModel(), appointment[i].GetEngine(), appointment[i].GetYear(), appointment[i].GetMileage(), appointment[i].GetType(), appointment[i].GetDate(), appointment[i].GetTime()});

        }catch(Exception ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,ex.getMessage(),"Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
      DefaultTableModel resultModel = new DefaultTableModel();
```

in NetBeans Design the table code is:

```
tableresult = new javax.swing.JTable(resultModel);

tableresult.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
    new Object [][] {
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null}
    },
    new String [] {
        "ID", "FName", "LName", "Registration", "Make", "Model", "Engine", "Type", "Date", "Time"
    }
));



jScrollPane1.setViewportView(tableresult);
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete. You show how you create the `resultModel` varialble and you show the code adding data to the TableModel. But you don't add the TableModel to the table. Post your [MCTRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you need more help.

Comment: Why is there a new `resultModel` declared _after_ you're using a `resultModel` above it?

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is simple : 
define a model of jtable with null parameters , than add this model to Jtable , in other part when you want retrieve data from data base you must declare two tables , the first will contain the header of table n the second will have  two dimensions  and will contain the data  as you need than you have to set then table as parameters to the model of jtable than add this model to jtable :) if you don't understand very well follow these codes :
this method to retrieve data from data base with tree parameters : 
sqlcounter query to count the number of row returned from the select query 
sql  query to select data from database 
NumberOfRowsToShowInTables is the number of row to show in the table it can be 0 or ten o other number as you wish
Rscounter is the Resultset of the statement stmt execution of the query sqlcounter
RsSelecting  is the resultset of the statement execution of the query sql 
Data table of string with two dimension 
header is the name of the colon of table in database

rs

```
public void SelectData(String sqlcounter ,String sql,int NumberOfRowsToShowInTables){
     if(NumberOfRowsToShowInTables==0){
         NumberOfRowsToShowInTables=10;
     }
        try {
         RsCounter=stmt.executeQuery(sqlcounter);
            System.out.println(sqlcounter);
            while(RsCounter.next()){

                countrow=RsCounter.getInt("COUNTR");
                System.out.println(countrow+"\n");
                if(NumberOfRowsToShowInTables>countrow)
                    NumberOfRowsToShowInTables=countrow;
                sql=sql+" LIMIT "+NumberOfRowsToShowInTables+" OFFSET "+(countrow-NumberOfRowsToShowInTables);  
                countrow=NumberOfRowsToShowInTables;

            }
            System.out.println(sql);
         RsSelecting = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
         data=new String[countrow][RsSelecting.getMetaData().getColumnCount()];

         header= new String[RsSelecting.getMetaData().getColumnCount()];

     i=0;
     while(RsSelecting.next()){
      for(j=0;j<RsSelecting.getMetaData().getColumnCount();j++){

              data[i][j]=(RsSelecting.getString(j+1));
              header[j]=RsSelecting.getMetaData().getColumnName(j+1);
              System.out.print(data[i][j]+"\n");

     }    


      i++;

     }
      i=j=0;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
                       ex.printStackTrace();

            Logger.getLogger(Connect.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
   }
```

than you get data and header with getter method

```
 public String [][] getData(){
       return data;
   }
   public String [] GetHeader(){
       return header;
   }
```

after that use then method to set these values as parameter of model

```
jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
model = new DefaultTableModel(data, header)
jTable1.setModel(model);
```

i wish it can be useful

Answer (score 0):

What I am doing to retrive data from `database` and display it on `JTable` using `Netbeans` is all this:

//Global Declaration

```
private Vector<Vector<String>> data; //used for data from database
private Vector<String> header; //used to store data header
```

//Display info to JTable

```
data = get();

//create header for the table
header = new Vector<String>();
header.add("Column1"); 
header.add("Column2");
...
model=new DefaultTableModel(data,header);
table = new JTable(model);
```

This will help you to get data from database

```
get(){
Vector<Vector<String>> doublevector = new Vector<Vector<String>>();

Connection conn = dbConnection();//Your Database connection code
PreparedStatement pre1 = conn.prepareStatement("select * from Table");

ResultSet rs1 = pre1.executeQuery();
while(rs1.next())
{
Vector<String> singlevector = new Vector<String>();
singlevector.add(rs1.getString(1)); 
singlevector.add(rs1.getString(2)); 
....
doublevector.add(singlevector);

}

return doublevector;
}
```